# What does instantiating an ActiveModel::Model class within itself provide from a design perspective?

Tags: validation, instantiation, ruby-on-rails-7

Assuming a PORO such as:

```rb
class Player
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :name, :position
  validates :name, :position
  

  VALID_POSITIONS = ['goalie', 'defense', 'forward']
  validates :position, :inclusion { in: VALID_POSITIONS}

  BENCH_WARMER = Player.new(name: "Biz", position: "bench_warmer")
end
```

1. How is `BENCH_WARMER` able to supersede the validation explicitly stated for the `position` attribute?
2. And what does this instantiation within itself of `BENCH_WARMER` afford the application/What can I do with `BENCH_WARMER` now that it exists within this class?
3. Why validate if it's simply going to be ignored in the next line?

Googling this sort of question points to a bunch of rudimentary resources about using `self` and how to create instances of an object outside of itself.